# IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status ...The agent crashed

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

The interface builder agent is crashing when I have the following code in the IBDesignable class.

```
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.mooButtonBackgroundColor
```

The representation of the color takes the form:

```
@nonobjc class var mooButtonBackgroundColor : UIColor {
    UIColor(named: "Color.Button.Background")!   // 0.129, 0.490, 0.851, 1
}
```

However, if I change the value returned to be:

```
@nonobjc class var mooButtonBackgroundColor : UIColor {
    .green //UIColor(named: "Color.Button.Background")!   // 0.129, 0.490, 0.851, 1
}
```

it all works.

I have also tried the method without the @nonobjc tag, with the same result.

Is there a restriction in IBDesigner that prevents using named colors?

Can someone suggest a method to overcome this crash in IBDesigner?

Comment: no difference with @objc

Comment: The designer can select the colors from the asset catalog, as they are available in the custom color select list for any object in the designer.  It must be something to do with UIColor init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Can someone suggest a method to overcome this crash in IBDesigner?

We can’t solve the named color problem, but we certainly can eliminate the crash by avoiding forced unwrapping operator, `!`. E.g. you could use a `nil`-coalescing operator, `??`, instead, so you have some fall-back color for IB, e.g.

```
backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Color.Button.Background") ?? .blue
```

But, if you don’t force unwrap, it won’t crash. And while it won’t use your named color in IB, it will when you run the app.

---

Personally, I’d avoid setting any properties usually set in IB (such as `backgroundColor`) in a designable view, itself. I think it’s exceedingly confusing to be looking at some view in IB, change a property, such as the background color, and not have it render correctly.

What can be configured in IB should probably be left in IB to avoid any confusion.

---

But let’s consider an example where I did want a custom color property to use a named color. I’d declare an `@IBInspectable` color property, e.g., consider this circle view with a custom `fillColor`:

```
@IBDesignable
class CircleView: UIView {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = .blue { didSet { shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor } }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePaths()
    }
}

private extension CircleView {
    func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
    }

    func updatePaths() {
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath
    }
}
```

I’d then set the named color in IB attributes inspector:

[image]

---

The other approach, is to not use named colors in the asset catalog, but rather define your own `UIColor` extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    static let buttonBackground = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
}
```

Then when you want to set some color property, you can do something like:

```
backgroundColor = .buttonBackground
```

The downside of this approach is that you lose the ability to use the named color within IB for other controls. But it’s another pattern to consider.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Very clear explanation.   I am using color catalog to handle dark mode.  I have overridden classes that contain a consistent configuration for all instances of that object, so the concept of presentation in IB is less important.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it turns out that this was a bug. Fixed in Xcode 11.4:

> Fixed a bug where using named colors in IBInspectable properties would use a fixed color at runtime, instead of the dynamic color from the asset catalog. (55248109) (FB7248211)